# The boundary proprerty of conjugate exponential family

Tags: self-study, normalization, exponential-family

Consider a conjugate prior in the k-parameter canonical exponential family:

$$p(w|n_0,y_0)=c(n_0,y_0) \exp(n_0(y_0 w'-b(w))) \, ,$$

where $n_0>0, y_0 \in Y$ is the pseudo observation vector, and $Y$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

I have to prove that the normalization constant $c(n_0,y_0)$ goes to zero when $y_0$ tends to the boundary of $Y$. Any suggestions?

I would like to find a proof that works both when $Y$ is bounded and unbounded (e.g. $Y=\mathbb{R}^k$).

Comment: You can use $\LaTeX$ by putting `$...$` or `$$...$$` around your code

Comment: since the conditional density is defined in the open subset $Y$, this means that it should be zero outside. Since the $Y$ is open, its boundary does not belong to it, hence it should be zero on it.

Comment: This result cannot hold as stated. If it did, one could replace $Y$ by a smaller open subset $Z$ with $y_0$ on its boundary, apply the desired result to $Z$ and conclude that $c(n_0,y_0)=0$ for *every* $y_0$ in $Y$.